# Express User Registration with MailChimp automation error

Tags: node.js, express, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm working on a project in Express that has user authentication and sends the user an email via MailChimp after registration.

### userRouter.js

```
//signup
userRouter.post('/signup', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, password, email } = req.body;
  const pwDigest = await bcrypt.hash(password, SALT);
  const newUser = await User.create({
    username: username,
    password_digest: pwDigest,
    email,
  });
  const tokenData = {
    username: newUser.username,
    email: newUser.email,
    id: newUser.id,
  };
  const token = genToken(tokenData);
  let userData = newUser.toJSON();
  let { password_digest, ...user } = userData;
  res.json({
    token,
    user,
  });
  request
        .post('https://' + mailchimpInstance + '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' + listUniqueId + '/members/')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + new Buffer('any:' + mailchimpApiKey ).toString('base64'))
        .send({
          'email_address': req.body.email,
          'status': 'subscribed'
        })
        .end(function(err, response) {
          if (response.status < 300 || (response.status === 400 && response.body.title === "Member Exists")) {
            res.send('Signed Up!');
          } else {
            res.send('Sign Up Failed :(');
          }
      });
});
```

Registration works fine and the user does get an email via MailChimp after signup. However, the Express server also crashes after registration:

```
_http_outgoing.js:535
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:535:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/Documents/myProjects/pages/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/Documents/myProjects/pages/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at /Users/Documents/myProjects/pages/routes/userRouter.js:48:17
    at Request.callback (/Users/Documents/myProjects/pages/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:879:3)
    at /Users/Documents/myProjects/pages/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:1100:20
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/Documents/myProjects/pages/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/parsers/json.js:22:7)
    at Stream.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Unzip.<anonymous> (/Users/Documents/myProjects/pages/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/unzip.js:53:12)
```

The error is occurring in server JS  `at /Users/Documents/myProjects/pages/routes/userRouter.js:48:17` where MailChimp is sending the post request.

If I remove the code for MailChimp, the error doesn't occur. Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This line `res.json({token, user,});` just before request, sends the response to the user, and then after getting a response from **mailchimp** , you try to send the response again. That's what causes the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I've been playing around with the line after your suggestion but still can't get it to work. Do you have any advice on how to chain these two requests?

Comment: Which request module are you using, might be because of deprecated function it's behaving such.

Comment: I'm using 'superagent' https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent

Comment: Try commenting `res.json({token, user,});` and see if the error persists, then we can chain them based on the use-case.